# A quadratic form problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a symmetric $n\times n$ real matrix $A$,if we have for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ ,$\|x\|_2=1$,and $x^tAx = c$ for some constant $c$.

Prove that $A = \lambda I$ for some $\lambda$.

My solution is since $A$is symmetric,we can take some orthogonal transformation $Q$ that makes $Q^tAQ$ as diagonal matrix $D = diag(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$, and we know $x \to q (=Qx)$ is an isomorphism on the sphere, so $q^tAq = c$ i,e, $\sum_n d_ix_i^2 = c$ so all the $d_i$ take the same value,so $A = dI$.

It's there some better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S=A-cI$. Then $x^TSx=0$ for every vector $x$. It follows from the polarisation identity that
$$
x^TSy=\frac14\left[(x+y)^TS(x+y)-(x-y)^TS(x-y)\right]=0
$$
for all vectors $x$ and $y$. In particular, $\|Sx\|^2=x^TS(Sx)=0$. Hence $Sx$ is identically zero, i.e. $A=cI$.

Comment: Was typing this answer. Good job.

Comment: nice solution,thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be any Eigenvector of $A$, associated to the Eigenvalue $\lambda$. By the definition of Eigenvalues,

$$x^TAx=\lambda x^Tx=\lambda$$

and by the given specific property of $A$,

$$x^TAx=c.$$

Hence all Eigenvalues are $c$ and $A=cI$.

Comment: This however still uses the fact that a symmetric real matrix is diagonalizable, which makes it not much different from the OP's solution.

Comment: @WhatsUp: that's right. Just a little more straigthforward.